# Is this sentence grammatically correct? 中国的建设开始的时候，人人是不以为过环境污染的。

Tags: grammar, mandarin

I'm trying to write:

> While construction began in China, people hadn't thought of the pollution.

Is this an accurate use of the grammar: shi4 ... de

Comment: 在中国建设刚开始起步时， 人们还没有考虑环境污染。

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'When construction began ..' and 'people didn't think about ....'??

Comment: **一开始** / **起初** 中国搞建设的时候 or 中国 **发展** / **建设** 的初期 or 中国 **发展** / **建设** 的初步阶段, and, 人没有考虑过环境污染 or 人人都没考虑过环境污染.

Answer (score 1):

When construction began in China, people didn't think about pollution.

当工业在中国兴起时，人们并没有想到污染的问题。

Answer (score 1):

1. Shorten as much as possible as long as the meaning remains the same, "*中国的建设开始的时候*" can be reduced to : "**中国的建设开始时**" (avoid two 的 in the same sentence)
2. *人人(everyone)* - use '**人们**'(people) as the subject instead is better.
3. *人们是不以为过* - the verb '是' should be omitted because 不以为 (didn't consider) is also a verb, so the sentence should be "**人们不以为过**"
4. *人们不以为过* - you tried to use '不' to indicate 'had not' but the correct term here should be 未曾 or **没有**
5. *人们没有以为过* - You try to use '以为' for 'considered' but the primary meaning of '以为' is 'thought' , the correct word for 'considered' is **考虑**
6. (a)  *人们没有考虑过环境污染的。* -- 境污染的 is an adjectival phrase, you need a noun after it, for example. 人们没有考虑过环境污染的**问题**。
7. (b). You can simply use '环境污染' (environmental pollution) as the noun and write "**人们没有考虑过环境污染**。"

> **Original sentence:**
>
> *中国的建设开始的时候，人人是不以为过环境污染的。*

~

> **Edition**:
>
> **中国的建设开始时，人们并没有考虑到环境污染的问题**。
>
> Add word particle '**并**' before  the verb '没有考虑' to emphasize ' something should had been done but hadn't)
>
> "没有考虑过"(had never considered) implies people deliberately ignored the problem;  replace 过 with 到 and write "没有考虑到" (had not considered) implies it was an oversight

Answer (score 0):

> 中国的建设开始的时候，人人是不以为过环境污染的

Incorrect, verb is wrong.

以为 -> 考虑, remove 是.

> 中国的建设开始的时候，人人都没有考虑过环境污染.

Retouch. 人人 -> 人们都

> 在中国的发展初期, 人们都没有考虑过环境污染的问题.

If you want to use 是....的 structure

> 在中国的发展初期, 人们是没有考虑环境污染的.

以为 followed by a statement

> 在中国的发展初期, 人们是以为**环境污染没有什么大不了的**.

Answer (score 0):

Corrected Version: 中国工业兴起时，人人认为污染环境是不以为过.

I don't think there is such thing as 中国建设。

不易为过is an adverb which should be modifying an action. 污染环境 is an action, 环境污染 is an issue (noun).